# Rewrite an url get parameter name

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite one parameter in my url and at the same time direct the traffic to another URL. The url should be called with an external program, so it does not actually need to redirect the user.

Original URL:

```
http://URL1/?parameter1=1234&monkey=12345
```

Should go into (changing URL1 > URL2 and monkey > abe:

```
http://URL2/?parameter1=1234&abe=12345
```

Searched alot of for mod_rewrite examples, but didn't find anything that rewrites the parameter name it self (not the value) and at the same time redirects to a different url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With mod_rewrite and whithout a client redir you cannot change the host.
If you try the following, you can change the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^parameter1=([0-9]+)&monkey=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule / /?parameter1=%1&abe=%2
```

But, in order to change the host, you must do a client redir:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^parameter1=([0-9]+)&monkey=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule / http://URL2/?parameter1=%1&abe=%2  [R]
```

Another option without client redir could be using a proxy; this way URL1's apache server, would proxy requests to URL2's web server and return the response to the client